# Problem with creating two docker containers: one postgreSQL and one pgadmin4 with a docker-compose.yml(PgAdmin Restarting Status)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, containers, pgadmin-4

Good evening everyone! I am writing to you as I am approaching the world of containerization for the very first time.

I have just installed "Docker" for Windows 10 and I need (for a project) to run the following "docker-compose.yml" which was not written by me and whose content is:

```
version: '3.3'

networks: 
  ntpgsql:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24

services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes: 
      - psdb-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address:  
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433 
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123_Stella
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: pgadmin4
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./dockervol
        target: /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/salvatore
    networks:
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=salvatore
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123_Stella


volumes:
  psdb-volume:
```

So I go to the folder where the docker-compose.yml file is contained and in Windows PowerShell I type

```
docker-compose up -d
```

After I have done this, I type the command

```
docker ps
```

but the Windows PowerShell tells me:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
3fd2bc3baa6e        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes                  0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   postgresql
fde27eed5949        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         11 minutes ago      Restarting (3) 8 seconds ago                            pgadmin4
```

But I can't understand why PgAdmin4 isn't working giving always the status "RESTARTING"!

(by the way, if I try to run the "docker-compose.yml" contained here: https://gist.github.com/tingwei628/8584ddefc5d8e85f73566d5ab96bdc84 everything works beautifully, including pigadmin4 that I can use directly from the UI of my browser).

Is there anyone experienced who can help me? Thanks a lot in advance ^^

Comment: It might be useful to run without `-d` flag so you could see the logs. Or use `docker-compose logs pgadmin` to see what's going on, why is it restarting. If it's something interesting you can post it here.

Comment: Hi @StefanGolubović! Thank you a lot for answering! I'have launched the command: docker logs fde27eed5949 and i got:
File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/paths.py", line 92, in init_app
    'The user does not have permission to read and write to the '
Exception: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory.
[2020-03-18 21:33:06 +0000] [80] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 80)
[2020-03-18 21:33:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-03-18 21:33:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: Ok @StefanGolubović, I have resolved by inserting /var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/salvatore instead of /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/salvatore. Thank you for supporting!